# UISegmentedControl and View switching problem

Tags: swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

So I've made a code in which I have 3 options in UISegmentedControl which should show you one of 3 Views ( green with 2 text fields, sub-view blue with 2 buttons and sub-view purple with 2 IUImageView)

At first everything looked easy, but then I've realized that my VC only  first View, and ignores 2 and 3. So when I click second and third segmented control all I see is a blanc screen.

 Weirdly, but when I've changed 1 seg control to show me blue view, instead of green, it also showed me blanc screen.

I'm still a beginner so it's hard for me to understand where is a problem here(

Maybe someone can help me.

Thanks!

[hierarchy in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOJ4c.png)

```
 import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        greenView.isHidden = false. // in this part I've tried to make the second view visible instead of first. It did not work. 
        
        blueView.isHidden = true
        purpleView.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var greenView: UIView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var blueView: UIView!
   
    @IBOutlet weak var purpleView: UIView!
    
    @IBAction func didChangeSC(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   
        switch  sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0 :
            greenView.isHidden = false
            
            blueView.isHidden = true
            purpleView.isHidden = true
            
        case 1 :
            blueView.isHidden = false
            
            greenView.isHidden = true
            purpleView.isHidden = true
        case 2 :
            purpleView.isHidden = false
            
            greenView.isHidden = true
            blueView.isHidden = true
            
            
        default:
            break
         
        }
    }
        
    
    
    

    /*
     // I've also tried to change the visibility but it didn't work.Here is how I did it.


     case 0 :
         greenView.alpha = 1
         
         blueView.alpha = 0
         purpleView.alpha = 0
         
     case 1 :
         blueView.alpha = 1
         
         greenView.alpha = 0
         purpleView.alpha = 0
     case 2 :
         purpleView.alpha = 1
         
         greenView.alpha = 0
         blueView.alpha = 0
     */
```

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of your view hierarchy in storyboard?

Comment: @SamB  I've added it to my question right above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `BlueView` and `PurpleView` are sub views of the `GreenView`. Since they are subViews, when you hide the `GreenView`, they also get hidden. So make all three views siblings (in the same level)

Now your view hierarchy is below

```
- View
  - GreenView
    - BlueView 
      - PurpleView
```

Change it to

```
- View
  - GreenView
  - BlueView 
  - PurpleView
```